# Shibboleth Dependency Error

Tags: amazon-ec2, shibboleth, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install Shibboleth on Amazon linux using the repo below.

```
[security_shibboleth]
name=Shibboleth (CentOS_7)
type=rpm-md
baseurl=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/shibboleth/CentOS_7/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/shibboleth/CentOS_7/repodata/repomd.xml.key
enabled=1
```

but I'm getting this dependency error.

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package shibboleth.x86_64 0:2.6.0-2.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-daemon.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_DAEMON_31)(64bit) for package: shibboleth-2.6.0-2.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-daemon.so.0()(64bit) for package: shibboleth-2.6.0-2.1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: shibboleth-2.6.0-2.1.x86_64 (security_shibboleth)
           Requires: libsystemd-daemon.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_DAEMON_31)(64bit)
Error: Package: shibboleth-2.6.0-2.1.x86_64 (security_shibboleth)
           Requires: libsystemd-daemon.so.0()(64bit)
```

Can someone please assist in resolving this error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Amazon linux is RHEL6 compatible, not RHEL7
this is what I have for my yum repo and it's been working fine for a while :

```
[shib.repo]
baseurl = http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/shibboleth/RHEL_6/
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1
gpgkey = http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/shibboleth/RHEL_6/repodata/repomd.xml.key
name = Shibboleth (RHEL_6)
```

<s>That said, the opensuse repo are currently down, see the note here : https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/latest/RPMS/</s>

> NOTE: As of the moment, Sep 6, 2017, the OpenSUSE site's publishing of
>   packages is offline. Until that changes, these packages are not going
>   to be available, no matter what you do. There is nothing the project
>   can do about that.

Opensuse repo is back up again

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't support Apache 2.4 therefore, it requires installing Apache 2.2. The environment I have has Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.0 installed.